# Basic confusion regarding definition of relative homology group $H_p(K;L)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am currently self-studying "Topology and Geometry for Physicists" by Nash and Sen, and have encountered a confusion regarding the definition of the relative homology group $H_p(K;L)$. The definition given is as follows :

The relative $p$-dimensional homology group of $K$ modulo $L$ is the quotient group
$$H_p(K;L) = Z_p(K;L)/B_p(K;L),p > 0$$
The members of $H_p(K;L)$ are $z_p+ C_p(L)$ (where as I understand it $z_p \in Z_p(K;L))$.

My question is : Why are the elements of $H_p(K;L)$ not given by $z_p + B_p(K;L)$ (using the definition of the quotient group)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated keeping in mind that I am a beginner in homology.

Comment: What is $C_p(L)$?

Comment: It is the free abelian group generated by the oriented $p$-simplexes of $L$ which itself a subcomplex of the complex $K$ with $L \subset K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, this statement is incorrect.  What I would guess is actually meant is that the elements of $Z_p(K;L)$ are of the form $z_p+C_p(L)$ (where $z_p\in C_p(K)$), since $Z_p(K;L)\subseteq C_p(K;L)=C_p(K)/C_p(L)$.  An element of $H_p(K;L)$ is then represented by an element of $Z_p(K;L)$ which has this form, modulo $B_p(K;L)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While reading through the text I also found a statement such as      " [$z_p + C_p(L) ] \in H_p (K;L)$ " which is still confusing to me.

Comment: Brackets like that usually mean "the equivalence class of".  So $[z_p+C_p(L)]$ is the equivalence class of $z_p+C_p(L)\in Z_p(K;L)$ modulo $B_p(K;L)$, which is an element of $Z_p(K;L)/B_p(K;L)=H_p(K;L)$.

Comment: So let's say I have a group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$, with the quotient group being $G/N$. The notation used to refer to elements of $G/N$ would be $[g]$ for $g \in G $ and not $[gN]$ ? Is this how the notation is normally used to refer to the classes ?

Comment: Because $[z_p + C_p(L) + B_p(K;L)]$ seemed more natural to me to refer to an element of $H_p(K;L)$. But as a beginner I am not sure.

Comment: The notation is _either_ $[g]$ or $gN$.  Putting brackets around $g$ means "the equivalence class (coset) of $g$".

Comment: Thank you so much. This gets rid of a lot of my confusion.